Frozen Account (cant sell or access token)
My Account status is Frozen, i cant sell my tokens or send them any where,
I got this error
Finalized (MAX Confirmations)
Program Error: "Instruction #4 Failed - Account is frozen"
Its on solscan here
https://solscan.io/tx/2rZEoxchAbLdi81e6vGKvpVUtZtfYSyEeRWbzuST7iJizf38q8imbm3mNqyGQ46FcxjEb54pyktxwbuef4bWtp3r
How can i Unfreeze my account so i can sell?

The error message you encountered, "Instruction #4 Failed - Account is frozen," indicates that your Solana account is currently frozen, which prevents you from performing transactions such as selling or transferring tokens. This typically happens for accounts associated with certain token programs or contracts that have the capability to freeze accounts for security or compliance reasons.
You will need to contact the entity that has the authority to freeze or unfreeze accounts. This is usually the token issuer or the administrative body managing the token. Look for their contact information on the token's official website or community channels like Discord, Telegram, or Twitter.
But if you got those tokens from an untrusted source, you're better off burning those tokens.

Looking at the token mint of provided token, it seems that the freeze authority wasn't revoked.
That means that the original minter 763uL5txLsGHxo5sidtu1zq7EUrPJjterywCd2hvWXrx has authority to freeze the tokens.
